# I'm using android simple_list_item_checked how should I highlight it when I click it

Tags: android, listview

following is my code

Main Activity

```
public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        String[] osArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.os_list);
        final ListView osListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.osListView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,osArray);
        osListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Main Activity xml file

How should I highlight the tick mark sign of the list view.

Answer (score 0):

for the listView in your xml file, set the following attribute

```
 for single choice item 
 android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 

 or this for multiple selection
 android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
```